# Two-neutrino oscillation model - reason for assumption

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos

In a [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.12028) done by the MiniBooNE experiment at Fermilab, it says in the abstract "If interpreted in a standard two-neutrino oscillation model". I understand they were using a muon neutrino beam that then oscillated occasionally into electron neutrinos, but there are also tau neutrinos. Why was it a reasonable assumption to "cut out" the tau neutrinos? Is it extremely low probability that muon neutrinos or electron neutrinos oscillate to tau neutrinos? Could their detection system not detect tau neutrinos?

Comment: To compare data with a model there have to be assumptions, their detector detects electron neutrinos  , the energy of the beam is such that no taus can be produced to check for tau neutrinos, and they find an excess of electron neutrinos when using the two neutrino model. It needs someone working on neutrino oscillations to reconcile contradictions between experiments with a new model. For example the Z LEP measurements fit with three neutrinos e mu tau very well. The one solar experiment that simultaneously measured  electron neutrinos and all neutrinos from the sun is consistent with

Comment: Z and the extended standard model for oscillations.  See my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409217/solar-neutrino-problem/409275#409275 Wait for a paper to reconcile all these.

Comment: @annav that effectively answers my question; why don't you write it up as an answer? My question was whether their detector cannot detect tau neutrinos/their beam doesn't allow for tau neutrinos, and it seems both are true, according to your comment.

Comment: Though it would be nice if you could expand on this, e.g., why is the energy of the beam high enough not to produce taus? What detection system do they use?

Comment: It is a comment because I do not really understand why they claim a new neutrino species on such evidence, i.e. an excess of electron neutrinos to some , for me, arbitrary model.   If I get a better understanding  I will come back to this question. they get their neutrinos from a beam of 8 Gev protons on beryllium, getting the neutrinos from the decays of  pions of the scatter.

Comment: see this blog by Motl for a summary https://motls.blogspot.com/2018/05/miniboone-confirms-lsnds-anomaly.html

Answer (score 3):

I emailed Professor [Kerry Whisnant](http://www.public.iastate.edu/%7Ewhisnant/homepage.html), who does research on neutrinos, and here is the answer he gave:

> To detect a tau neutrino, you would have to have an interaction in your detector in which a tau lepton is produced (remember neutrinos couple to charged leptons in the weak interactions), and there is not enough energy in the beam to do that. There have been more energetic neutrino beams where there are oscillations to tau neutrinos, which then are detected by seeing taus, but not MiniBooNE. Tau neutrinos have also been detected in atmospheric neutrinos since some of those are very energetic. So there could have been (and likely were) oscillations to tau neutrinos in MiniBooNE, too, but they would not have been detected.
>
> The reason the MiniBooNE result suggests sterile neutrinos is that oscillations depend on both the distance traveled and the neutrino energy (the exact statement is that it depends on L divided by E). But it also depends on the difference of the squared masses. Solar neutrinos indicate one value for this difference (7.6x10^(-5) eV^2) and atmospheric neutrinos indicate another (2.5x10^(-3) eV^2), but because of their L and E, the LSND and MiniBooNE results indicate a much larger value (more like 1 eV^2). But the only way to have three very different values for the squared mass differences is to have four different neutrino masses. And because it has been known since the 1990's that there are only three active neutrinos (neutrinos that have standard weak interactions), a fourth neutrino must be "sterile," i.e., it does not have the usual weak interactions.
>
> Regarding the two-neutrino model analysis (Fig. 5 in their paper), with four neutrinos, there are actually six different mixing angles. At the particular L and E of MiniBooNE (and LSND), the amplitude of the nu_mu to nu_e oscillation is some combination of those mixing angles, and it can be approximated as a two-neutrino oscillation. But all possible oscillations actually occur (although some may be so unlikely that they are not visible).